# Extract values from one table to another by matching

Tags: r, loops, match

I'm wokring on matching two tables and extracting values from the major table to another table.

I've two tables (pls see the image below):

[image]

"Table 1" consists of values for coordinates at different dates; this table has one million of rows (each represent a coordinate) and three thousands of columns (each column represents a specific date)
"Table 2" looks similar to Table 1. But values of the "Table 2" cells are the colnames of "Table 1".

Aim: To extract values from "Table 1" cells to "Table 2" cells based on the "date ..."  and "coordinate" in both tables.

A simple loop was created (see code below). But it takes too much time to get the results.

```
table1<-data.frame(longitude=10:12,
                   latitude=20:22,
                   a=1:3,
                   b=2:4,
                   c=3:5,
                   d=4:6)
colnames(table1)[3:6]<-c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04")
table1
table2<-data.frame(longitude=10:12,
               latitude=20:22,
               date1=c("2020-01-02","2020-01-04","2020-01-03"),
               date2=c("2020-01-04","2020-01-02","2020-01-01"),
               date3=c("2020-01-03","2020-01-02","2020-01-04"))
table2
for(i in 1:nrow(table1)){
   w<-table2[i,-(1:2)]
   for(j in 1:length(w)){
   table2[i,j+2]<-table1[i,which(colnames(table1) %in% w[j])]
 }}
table2
```

Much appreciated if someone can share the solution in R with me.
for a table with millions of rows and thousands of columns

Comment: An example has been given. look forward to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach using `lapply` -

```
#columns of interest in table1
col1 <- grep('\\d+-\\d+-\\d+', names(table1), value = TRUE)
#columns of interest in table2
col2 <- grep('date\\d+', names(table2))
#Create a sequence of row numbers for table1
n <- seq(nrow(table1))

#For each column use match to get corresponding value
table2[col2] <- lapply(table2[col2], function(x) 
                       table1[col1][cbind(n, match(x, col1))])
table2

#  longitude latitude date1 date2 date3
#1        10       20     2     4     3
#2        11       21     5     3     3
#3        12       22     5     3     6
```

Comment: Dear Ronak Shah, thanks for your great sharing. It's fairy useful and time-saving. For a table with millions of rows and thousands of columns, it only takes less than one minute to be completed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
table2 %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('date'),
    ~ table1[cbind(match(longitude, table1$longitude), 
        match(., names(table1)))]))
  longitude latitude date1 date2 date3
1        10       20     2     4     3
2        11       21     5     3     3
3        12       22     5     3     6
```

Comment: Dear akrun, much appreciate your solution. It works quite well for my case.